# Question about Landau's derivation of the energy relation in Statistical Physics (Vol 5)

Tags: classical-mechanics, statistical-mechanics, adiabatic

In Statistical Physics (Vol 5 of Landau's books) section 11, Landau derives an important relation: $\overline{\frac{\partial E(p, q;\lambda)}{\partial \lambda}} = \left(\frac{\partial E}{\partial \lambda}\right)_S$.

In his derivation, there is an important step:
[image]

He argues that **averaging over statistical distribution and differentiating with respect to time can be interchanged**.

But since formally, $E = \int f(p, q; \lambda(t)) E(p, q; \lambda(t)) d^3 p d^3 q$, where $f(p, q; \lambda(t))$ is the statistical distribution, it seems that the interchange is illegal? Or we must assume that under the time $dt$, the change in $f(p, q; \lambda(t))$ is small and can be ignored?(Is it a consequence of adiabatic condition?)

Am I not getting the point of adiabatic condition?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Note that the derivative with respect to $\lambda$ in Landau is being taken at fixed entropy $S$.  This means that the probability distribution is not changing. This will happen if the change is slow eneough that the quantum adiabatic theorem holds --- meaning that the system  stays in the same quantum state.

When you include the change in ditribution this gives rise to  the $TdS$ part of
$$ 
dU = T\,dS-P\, dV.
$$

For example, given  a  Hamiltonian $\hat H$ whose   eigenstates $|n\rangle$ have  energy $E_n$, the canonical ensemble  assigns  a probability
$$
\rho_n =  \frac 1 Z  e^{-\beta E_n}
$$
to the state $|n\rangle$.
Here $\beta=1/T$ and
$$
Z= \sum_n e^{-\beta E_n}={\rm tr}\left\{e^{-\beta H}\right\}
$$
is the partition function.
The thermodynamic internal energy $U$ is then
$$
U= \frac 1 Z \sum_nE_n e^{-\beta E_n}.
$$

For any probability  distribution $\rho_n$, the associated entropy is defined to be
$$
S= - \sum_n  \rho_n \ln \rho_n
$$
For the canonical distribution, this leads to
$$
S=  \frac 1 Z \sum_n \left( \frac{E_n}{T} +\ln Z\right) e^{-\beta E_n}= \frac U T +\ln Z.
$$
A change in the distribution leads to a change in the entropy of
$$
\delta S = -\sum_n (\ln \rho_n) \delta \rho_n.
$$
Here we have use the fact that $\sum_n \rho_n=1$ implies that  $\sum_n\delta  \rho_n=0$.

Let the Hamiltonian depend on a parameter $\lambda$  (the system volume, for example). The energy levels $E_n(\lambda)$ then also depend  on $\lambda$, and we  use the symbol ``$P$'' to stand for the generic  thermodynamic average
$$
P= -\left\langle \frac{ d\hat H}{d\lambda}\right\rangle \nonumber\\
=- \frac 1 Z \sum_n \left( \frac{d E_n}{d\lambda}\right) e^{-\beta E_n}.\nonumber
$$

Thus
$$
\delta U =  \frac 1 Z \sum_n \left(\frac{d E_n}{d\lambda}\right)\,  \delta \lambda  e^{-\beta E_n} + \sum_n E_n\, \delta\left(\frac 1 Z e^{-\beta E_n}\right)\nonumber\\
= -P\,  d\lambda + T \sum_n \left( \frac{E_n}{T} +\ln Z\right) \delta \left(\frac 1 Z e^{-\beta E_n}\right)\nonumber\\
= -P\, d\lambda + T \sum_n (-\ln \rho_n) \delta \rho_n\nonumber\\
= -P\, d\lambda  +T dS.\nonumber
$$
In  passing from the first line to the second, we are allowed to insert the ``$T\ln Z$''  because $\sum \delta\rho_n=0$.